# Изменить list объектов

Tags: java, java-stream

```
public class WorkerInfo {
    privat Worker worker;
    // геттеры и сеттеры
}

public class Worker {
    privat Long id;
    privat String name;
    privat Double salary;
    privat String error;
    // геттеры и сеттеры
}
```

На вход поступает List <WorkerInfo> необходимо проверить поле salary, если оно null, то устанавливаем в поле error значение "Зарплата не установлена" иначе error равно "".
Циклом я это сделал, не получается сделать через Stream API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так себе задача для стримов, но можно , к примеру, так:

```
List<WorkerInfo> result = list.stream()
        .peek(w->w.getWorker().setError(w.getWorker().getSalary()==null ? "Зарплата не установлена" : ""))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Спасибо, это решение моей проблемы! А почему это так себе задача для стрима?

Comment: Потому что для перебора элементов и их изменения лучше использовать обычные циклы. Ни один метод в `Stream API` не подходит идеологически для этой задачи (исходя из соображений чистоты). Тот же самый `peek` использовать для таких целей — это антипаттерн https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/308977/is-it-an-antipattern-to-use-peek-to-modify-a-stream-element

Comment: Спасибо! Буду иметь ввиду

Answer (score 0):

Stream API не совсем подходит для решения данной задачи, так как она подразумевает изменение (мутацию) содержимого списка, то есть использование *побочного эффекта* в операции `Stream::peek` или даже [`Stream::forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) в общем случае *крайне* не рекомендуется, так как операции над стримами должны "не вмешиваться" в источник стрима и не зависеть от состояния стрима (каждый элемент стрима не зависит от какого-либо другого):

> *Most stream operations accept parameters that describe user-specified behavior... To preserve correct behavior, these behavioral parameters:*
>
> - must be non-interfering (they do not modify the stream source);
> - and in most cases must be stateless (their result should not depend on any state that might change during execution of the stream pipeline)._

Однако есть возможность применить метод родительского интерфейса [`Iterable::forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-), предназначенный для подобного рода задач, так как здесь используется итератор в функциональном стиле:

```java
list.forEach(wi -> wi.getWorker().setError(
    null == wi.getWorker().getSalary() ? "Зарплата не установлена" : ""
));
```